# Субстантивация местоимения ТОТ в конструкциях типа НА ТОМ, ЧТО

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, местоимения

Местоимение *тот* в словарях приводится как *местоимение-прилагательное*. В связи с этим хочется проанализировать следующее употребление:

> Во второй главе вы будете акцентировать внимание **на том, что** может помешать вам построить надёжный дом.

Сохраняет ли в приведённом выше примере местоимение *тот* признаки *местоимения-прилагательного*? Если да, то какой член предложения оно определяет? Помогите разобраться.

*P.S.* Дополнительно хочется заметить, что местоимение *этот* совершенно явно может употребляться в качестве *местоимения-существительного*:

> не следует акцентировать **на этом** внимание работодателей

Answer (score 2):

1) **Местоимения имеют двойную классификацию**. По морфологическим признакам они делятся на местоименные существительные, прилагательные, числительные и наречия. По семантическим признакам они делятся на 9 разрядов.

2) Местоимения ***этот*** и ***тот*** относятся к местоименным прилагательным, а по семантике это указательные местоимения.

3) Местоимения ***этот*** и ***тот*** имеют парадигму склонения **по образцу прилагательных** (кроме И.п. и В.п.), то есть изменяются **по родам, числам и падежам**: тот — того — тому, то — того — тому, та — той — той и т.д.

4) Местоименные прилагательные ***этот*** и ***тот*** могут выполнять **функцию определения**: *тот человек, то место*, а могут **переходить** в  существительные в конкретном предложении: *тот, то, этот, это*, то есть употребляются **в значении**  существительных.

В то же время они **не образуют нового класса слов**, а остаются **грамматическими прилагательными**. Этот переход называется **субстантивацией**, и он характерен для всех прилагательных, а не только для местоименных.

Сравнить: *столовая, портной* — полная субстантивация, *моя знакомая (девушка)* — неполная (временная) субстантивация.

Соответственно, более точным является термин **субстантивированное местоименное прилагательное.**

5) Местоименное (субстантивированное) прилагательное в форме среднего рода ***то*** часто используется в качестве **указательного слов**а в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными или местоименно-определительными.

6) **Разбор предложения**

*Во второй главе вы будете акцентировать внимание **на том, что** может помешать вам построить надёжный дом.*

Здесь местоимение ***то*** в форме П.п. является указательным словом в СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным (местоименная пара ***на том — что***). Местоимение является **дополнением** в главном предложении: акцентировать внимание (на чём).

7) *Не следует акцентировать **на этом** внимание работодателей..*.

***На этом*** — местоименное (субстантивированное) прилагательное ***это*** в форме П.п.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый комментарий. А есть ли подтверждение возможности субстантивации местоимения *тот* в академических грамматиках? Буду премного благодарен за такую ссылку.

Comment: Текст ответа исправлен. Термин местоименные существительные применяется к определенному разряду местоимений, а при переходе  в существительное лучше говорить о СУБСТАНТИВИРОВАННЫХ местоименных прилагательных.  О классификации местоимений можно прочесть в Грамматике-80. https://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1744#1277 Что касается перехода, то там эта тема подробно не рассматривается, но в любом учебнике по морфологии есть раздел, посвященный субстантивации прилагательных.  В данном случае такой переход очевиден: этот/тот человек - этот/тот, этот/тот предмет - это/то.

Comment: В то же время следует отметить, что для местоимения "тот" субстантивация является довольно устойчивой. К примеру, это местоимение регулярно используется в качестве указательного слова в СПП, оно входит в составные союзы (несмотря на то что, для того чтобы и др.).